# Data binding not updated for CollectionViewSource which source has been grouped or sorted

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, grouping

I have a Windows Store app (or Metro style / WinRT / Windows Runtime) that has a CollectionViewSource that is bound to a ListView in the codebehind file. Without sorting and/or grouping all works fine and the UI gets updated. But as soon as I sort or group the CollectionViewSource's Source, the UI stops updating. Set the binding in MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ViewModel = new MainPageVm();
    DataContext = ViewModel;

    Binding myBinding = new Binding();
    myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    myBinding.Source = ViewModel.UpcomingAppointments;
    UpcomingListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
    //Timer to update the UI periodically
    var Timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)};
    Timer.Tick += (o, e) => ViewModel.LoadData();
    Timer.Start();
}
```

The relevant part of the viewmodel:

```
public class MainPageVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageVm()
    {
        Appointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>();
        Appointments.CollectionChanged += delegate { NotifyPropertyChanged("UpcomingAppointments"); };
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Appointment> Appointments
    {
        get { return appointments; }
        set
        {
            if (appointments != value)
            {
                appointments = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UpcomingAppointments");
            }
        }
    }


    public CollectionViewSource UpcomingAppointments
    {
        get
        {
            return new CollectionViewSource
            {
               //removing Where an Groupby and set IsSourceGrouped = false get the UI updated again
                Source = Appointments
                    .Where(a => a.Start > DateTime.UtcNow) 
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Day),
                IsSourceGrouped = true
            }; 
        }
    }


    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        var Repo = new WebserviceRepository();
        await Repo.GetAppointments();

        Appointments.Clear;
        foreach (Appointment Appointment in Repo.Appointments)
        {
            Appointments.Add(Appointment);
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UpcomingAppointments");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Appointments");
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And the relevant XAML part:

```
<ListView Name="UpcomingListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AppointmentListTemplate}">              

<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

And finally the Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public Guid AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Day
    {
        get
        { 
           if (this.Start.Date == DateTime.Now.Date){return "Today";}
           if (this.Start.Date == (DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date)) { return "Tomorrow";}
           If (this.Start.Date == (DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).Date)){ return "Day After Tomorrow";}
           return string.Empty;         
        }
    }
}
```

So deleting the .Where and .Sort and set IsSourceGrouped to false makes the UI update again, but of course unsorted and not the desired grouping.

When I set data in the constructor of the ViewModel, that data is displayed (grouped or not) but not updated

As you can see I call NotifyPropertyChanged whenever LoadData is run, just to be sure that it is called. I also run NotifyPropertyChanged after the Appointments OberservableCollection-s Collection has changed.

Apparently the Where filtering and the GroupBy grouping needs some other tweaks that I am not aware of. I see a lot of question on SO about grouping, but it seems that they are about WPF (and that is different) or set all the bindings and static resources in XAML (and I don't want to do that).

So my basic question is: How can I group and sort the UpcomingAppointments in a ListView using the C# codebehind file?